# What is the infimum over $x$ of the lagrangian function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I am learning about duality in convex optimisation. The Lagrangian is defined as $$L(x, \lambda, \nu) = f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(x) + \sum_{i=1}^p\nu_ih_i(x)$$ where suppose the optimisation problem has $m$ inequality and $p$ equality constraints. The Lagrangian dual function is defined as $$g(\lambda, \nu) = inf_{x \in D}L(x,\lambda,\nu)$$

Given a set of numbers (1-D case), I know that the infimum is the greatest lower bound on this set of numbers. How does the definition of infimum extend to the multivariate case as in the Lagrangian dual function?

Comment: The set of values of $L(x,\lambda,\nu)$ is a set of real numbers so the inf that you're looking for is the greatest lower bound on this set.

Comment: Wouldn’t the infimum over x return a function over lambda and nu? We need all three values to get a real number?

Comment: Yes, $g(\lambda,\nu)$ is a function of $\lambda$ and $\nu$.

Comment: so the infimum over x returns a function of $\lambda$ and $\nu$. How do we interpret this function as a greatest lower bound as it is not a set of real numbers?

Comment: Fix $\lambda$ and $\nu$.  Then the set of values of $L(x,\lambda,\nu)$ is a set of real numbers that has an infinum.  That inf is $g(\lambda,\nu)$.

Comment: okay i think i got it. Thanks!